# Android Floating Action button : Resize inside icon

Tags: java, android

[image]

Hi I want to set image into FloatingActionButton  i did this :

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/qick_menu"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            android:src="@drawable/quick_menu"
            app:elevation="7dp"
            app:layout_anchor="@id/mapview"
            app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end" />
```

But I have a small image in my button

Comment: please show what you want

Comment: @KiranBennyJoseph I want to remove this border and put image for full size

Comment: Change your image, it has borders.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

try this: in Layout:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/map"
        app:backgroundTint="@android:color/transparent"
        app:borderWidth="0dp"
        app:useCompatPadding="true" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Now in res/values/dimens.xml:

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <!-- Default screen margins, per the Android Design guidelines. -->
    <dimen name="fab_margin">16dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="design_fab_image_size" tools:override="true">56dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

This line is important `<dimen name="design_fab_image_size" tools:override="true">56dp</dimen>`

output:

[image]

Comment: Many Thanx , after 1 hour searching and applying to code found, what i exactly want.

Comment: Do you know the original value of `design_fab_image_size`?

Comment: this is then applied to every fab button in the project, correct? =(

Comment: How to apply it only to some of the FAB buttons in the app?

Answer (score 5):

you can use `fabSize` [attribute](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/FloatingActionButton.html#attr_android.support.design:fabSize)

```
app:fabSize="normal"
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this: android:scaleType="center" and try image size 56dp. It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

The image/icon inside `FAB` can be resized in XML.

`app:maxImageSize = "32dp"` This will be your image size inside Floating Action Button.

`app:fabCustomSize = "64dp"` This will be your Floating Action Button size.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the image if you want to change the size of the inner image, just choose the image of your choice and add it to floating button.

Comment: So how I can do this ?

Comment: You can use ImageAsset provided by android studio or download from internet , and then use src property in floating button tag in xml @KrzysztofPokrywka

Comment: <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_work"
         />

Comment: I made the image from ImageAsset in android studio and then simple used in src, take a look at above comment @KrzysztofPokrywka